# x axis with duplicate values (loading profile) plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, graph, plot, matplotlib

i have load profile data where x axis is load profile such that for multiple same values of x (constant load) i have different values for y.
till now in excel i used to line plot y and right click graph->selec data->change hoizontal axis data by providing it range o x axis data and that used to give me the graph

[image: Sample Chart]

the problem i have is when i try to give 
plot(x,y), matplotlib plots y for unique vals of x ie it neglects out all the remaining value of for same value of x.
and when i plot with plot(y) i get sequence numbers on x axis
i tried xticks([0,5,10,15]) for checking out but couldn't get the required result.
my question is
is it possible to plot a graph in a similar fashion as of excel
the other alternative i could think of was plotting plot(y and plot (x) with same horizontal axis it atleast gives a pictorial idea but is there any means to do it the excel way??

Comment: Show us your code, and tell us what the problem is, not a story about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds to me like you want to use the "scatter" plotting command instead of the "plot" plotting command. This will allow the use of redundant x-values. Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data that has non-unique x-values
x1 = np.linspace(1,50)
y1 = x1**2
y2 = 2*x1
x3 = np.append(x1,x1)
y3 = np.append(y1,y2)

# Now plot it using the scatter command
# Note that some of the abbreviations that work with plot,
# such as 'ro' for red circles don't work with scatter
plt.scatter(x3,y3,color='red',marker='o')
```

[image: scatter plot]

As I mentioned in the comments, some of the handy "plot" shortcuts don't work with "scatter" so you may want to check the documentation: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot `y-values` for a given `x-values`, you need to get the index which has same x-values. If you are working with `numpy` then you can try

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1]*5+[2]*5+[3]*5)
y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5]*3)
idx=(x==1) # Get the index where x-values are 1
plt.plot(y[idx],'o-')
plt.show()
```

If you are working with lists you can get the index by

```
# Get the index where x-values are 1
idx=[i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

just answering own question,found this around when i had posted this question years back :)

```html
def plotter(y1,y2,y1name,y2name):
    averageY1=float(sum(y1)/len(y1))
    averageY2=float(sum(y2)/len(y2))
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)  
    ax1.plot(y1,'b-',linewidth=2.0)
    ax1.set_xlabel("SNo")
    # Make the y2-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1name, color='b')
    for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
        tl.set_color('b')
    ax1.axis([0,len(y2),0,max(y1)+50])
    
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    
    ax2.plot(y2, 'r-')
    ax2.axis([0,len(y2),0,max(y2)+50])
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2name, color='r')
    for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
        tl.set_color('r')
    plt.title(y1name + " vs " + y2name)
    #plt.fill_between(y2,1,y1)
    plt.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')

    plt.savefig(y1name+"VS"+y2name+".png",dpi=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(len(x)), y)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: with `set_xticklabels` you can set ticks labels, it works even with duplicated labels